# How do "air nozzles" in airplanes concentrate air flow so well?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm working on a project that requires concentrating air flow into a beam such that it can travel longer distances through an unconstrained medium (i.e. open space, not a hose).

Something that came to mind are those little air nozzles that you find on air planes. These seem to do a pretty good job of directing air through a narrow path such that it doesn't effect nearby passengers.

What kind of mechanism is used to maintain this tight air flow?

Comment: suggest you ask this question on the aviation stack exchange.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I was unsure where to post this but ultimately posted here since I assumed it was fluid dynamics related.

Comment: it is indeed, but it is more engineering-related than theoretical. the aviation exchange has a good mixture of both sorts of experts, and they are helpful people.

Comment: @Izzo I've had luck with a [fluid dynamics question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/11963/6264) in Engineering SE. I think it could go either way in Aviation SE, it is an equipment question rather than a passenger experience question, so it might work.

Answer (score 0):

The first trick is to get the air molecules flowing in just one direction.  You can do this by forcing them through a 'bundle of straws' rather than one tube.

Comment: That's an interesting concept, similar to collimating light but with air.

Comment: @Izzo They're called straightners I believe, for use in wind tunnels.